# Adding an argument to compile mode from "Local Variables"

Tags: auctex

I have the following code in my .emacs file

```
(push
   '("Latexmk" "latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -pdflatex='pdflatex -synctex=1 -file-line-error' -pdf %t" TeX-run-TeX nil t
     :help "Run Latexmk on file") TeX-command-list)
```

However, I would like to compile certain files with additional arguments (like "--shell-escape"), but I don't want to always have that option and I prefer not to create a separate command for it.

Is there a way to specify these arguments locally in a file so that they are passed to `latexmk`? Perhaps something like this at the end of the file

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% compile-args: --shell-escape
%%% End:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TeX-expand-list` to add your own expanders like `%e`:

```el
(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%e" my-TeX-expand-shell-escape))

(defvar-local my-TeX-expand-shell-escape nil
              "Add --shell-escape to the LaTeX command line if `my-TeX-expand-shell-escape' is true.")

(defun my-TeX-expand-shell-escape ()
  "Substitute %e by --shell-escape in commands from `TeX-command-list'."
  (if my-TeX-expand-shell-escape
      "--shell-escape"
    ""))
```

Customize `TeX-command-list` to include that expander. For an example you can change the `Command` of the `LaTeX` entry from

`` %`%l -file-line-error -file-line-error %(mode)%' %t ``

to

`` %`%l -file-line-error  %e -file-line-error %(mode)%' %t ``.

Afterwards you can use `my-TeX-expand-shell-escape` as file-local variable for adding the `--shell-escape` switch to the LaTeX command.

Comment: I noticed that with this solution, if I have a master file with `my-TeX-expand-shell-escape` set but then I compile in some other file that sets its master file, then `--shell-escape` is *not* passed. So I always have to compile from the master file. Is there a way to resolve this? Also, is there a way to have a "compile-args" local variable as in the question?